# Analytic solution of differential equation $y'=(x+y-1)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $$y'=(x+y-1)^2$$ which I am trying to solve for the value of $x=2$. I have already done a Euler method approximation but when trying to find the exact value of the equation I am finding that the exact solution involves various imaginary terms. I am unsure of how to extend these imaginary terms into real values.

Is anyone sure how I would extend a real value to this equation?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Lets define $u=x+y-1$. Then $u^{\prime}=1+y^{\prime}$ and the equation becomes

$$u^{\prime}=1+u^{2}$$

$$\int\frac{{\rm d}u}{1+u^{2}}=\int{\rm d}x$$

$$\arctan{u}=x+C$$

$$u=\tan{\left(x+C\right)}$$

$$y=\tan{\left(x+C\right)}-x+1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Change variables to $$u := x + y - 1 ,$$ so that $y' = u' - 1$; then, the original equation becomes the autonomous, separable equation
$$u' = u^2 + 1.$$